# Unordered categorical variables and linear regression

Tags: regression, categorical-data, generalized-linear-model, logit

I am new to this forum and still quite novice with regards to statistics.

In my M.A. thesis I use one binary dependent variable and one unordered categorical dependent variable in separate estimations. I am therefore trying to get an oversight over the debate of whether to use linear or logistic regression when handling discrete dependent variables.

The debate of whether linear regression (the Linear Probability Model) is suitable to estimate a binary outcome seems to be still ongoing. Some authors argue that the LPM is inferior to logistic regression, while others argue that it functions just as well. I therefore report results using both these models when handling the binary dependent variable.

I am however struggling to find any similar debate with regards to unordered categorical variables with more than two choices. The sources Ive read simply recommend using a multinomial logistical model while referring to the fact that discrete dependent variables violate the normality and homoskedasticity assumptions. This violation is however also done by the LPM model.

Is there no viable alternatives using linear regression when estimating unordered categorical variables?

Any kind of feedback will be greatly appreciated!